# Сериализация Enum в JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, enum

Как сериализовать в JSON перечисление?

```
from enum import Enum


class Color(Enum):
    RED = 'red'
    GREEN = 'green'
    BLUE = 'blue'


data = [
    {
        'name': 'car',
        'color': Color.RED,
    },
    {
        'name': 'dog',
        'color': Color.BLUE,
    },
]

import json
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

При выполнении `dumps` происходит ошибка: `TypeError: <Color.RED: 'red'> is not JSON serializable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы поддерживать произвольные `Enum`, сохраняя их в JSON формате по имени:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(dict(color=Color.GREEN),
...            default=lambda obj: obj.name if isinstance(obj, Enum) else obj)
'{"color": "GREEN"}'
```

Это работает при произвольном определении `Enum`, к примеру:

```
from enum import Enum, auto

class Color(Enum):
    RED = auto()
    GREEN = auto()
    BLUE = auto()
```

Comment: О, здоворо выглядит с использование параметра `default`

Answer (score 2):

Для решения этой проблемы нужно свой класс перечисления дополнительно наследовать от нужного типа, в данном случае от `str`, тогда при сериализации проблем не возникнет:

Для удобства можно завести для этого перечисление `StrEnum` и наследовать от него свои перечисления:

```
class StrEnum(str, Enum):
    pass

class Color(StrEnum):
    ...

class Currency(StrEnum):
    ...
```

---

**Решение:**

```
import json
from enum import Enum


class Color(str, Enum):
    RED = 'red'
    GREEN = 'green'
    BLUE = 'blue'

data = [
    {
        'name': 'car',
        'color': Color.RED,
    },
    {
        'name': 'dog',
        'color': Color.BLUE,
    },
]
   
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

**Консоль:**

```
[
    {
        "name": "car",
        "color": "red"
    },
    {
        "name": "dog",
        "color": "blue"
    }
]
```

Comment: наследовать от str здесь стоит, только если у вас есть уже существующее API, которое строки принимает. Иначе вы не можете гарантировать свойства Enum. К примеру, `color is Color.RED` это верное выражение для Enum, но если color это `str()`, то может быть так что `color == Сolor.RED` (с вашим определнием Enum), но одновременно при этом `color is not Color.RED` (с обычным определением Enum всегда было бы `"red" != Color.RED` вне зависимости от значения `Color.RED.value`). `Color(str, Enum)` следует использовать только в случаях, когда Color(Enum) не работает (json.dumps работает и с Color(Enum))

Comment: `is` ведь проверяет ссылку, а сравнивать значение с перечислением через оператор `is`, а не `==` странно, к остальному не придраться :)

Comment: Enum используют `is` для сравнения (Enum это специальный случай, это не обычный класс) https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#comparisons